Proving one one condition for the Gaussian mixture model
$\textbf{Question:}$ Consider the following matrix representation for a two-component bivariate Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM):
$S = \begin{bmatrix}
A & X \\
X' & B
\end{bmatrix}$
where
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_1 + \pi_1\mu_1\mu_1' & 0 \\
0 & \Sigma_2 + \pi_2\mu_2\mu_2'
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
X = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi_1\mu_1 & 0 \\
0 & \pi_2\mu_2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi_1 & 0 \\
0 & \pi_2
\end{bmatrix}$
Here, $\Sigma_i$ are 2×2 covariance matrices, $\mu_i$ are 2×1 mean vectors, and $\pi_i$ are mixing coefficients (with $\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1$).
I want to know the potential issues in proving that this representation a one-to-one correspondence between GMM parameters and the embedded matrix S. Specifically:
Show that different sets of parameters $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \Sigma_1, \Sigma_2, \pi_1)$ and $(\mu_1', \mu_2', \Sigma_1', \Sigma_2', \pi_1')$ can potentially lead to the same matrix S.
I want to know is there any condition that we need to put on the Covariance $\Sigma$ to make this one-one. I am guessing that this covariance term will create an issue in proving one-one.

Thank you for the answer, it is very helpful!

$\newcommand\Si\Sigma$The parameter quintuple $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \Si_1, \Si_2, \pi_1)$ is uniquely determined (UD) by $S$ if and only if $\pi_1\notin\{0,1\}$.
Indeed, $B$ is UD by $S$ and hence the pair $(\pi_1,\pi_2)$ is UD by $S$. Next, $X$ is UD by $S$ and hence the pair $(\pi_1\mu_1,\pi_2\mu_2)$ is UD by $S$, so that the pair $(\pi_1\mu_1\mu'_1,\pi_2\mu_2\mu'_2)$ is UD by $S$ -- provided $\pi_1\notin\{0,1\}$.
Further, $A$ is UD by $S$ and hence the pair $(\Si_1+\pi_1\mu_1,\Si_2+\pi_2\mu_2)$ is UD by $S$, so that the pair $(\Si_1,\Si_2)=(\Si_1+\pi_1\mu_1,\Si_2+\pi_2\mu_2)-(\pi_1\mu_1\mu'_1,\pi_2\mu_2\mu'_2)$ is UD by $S$.
Thus, the parameter quintuple $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \Si_1, \Si_2, \pi_1)$ is UD by $S$ if $\pi_1\notin\{0,1\}$.
If now $\pi_1=0$, then $\mu_1$ can be any $2\times1$ vector, without affecting $S$. Finally, if $\pi_1=1$, then $\pi_2=0$ and $\mu_2$ can be any $2\times1$ vector, without affecting $S$. $\quad\Box$
